# What metrics can be used to quantify underestimation of uncertainties?

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis, statistics, experimental-technique

Suppose an experiment measures a quantity to be $5 \pm 0.3$ and another measures it to be $9 \pm 0.3$

What metrics can be used to emphasize and quantify the error in the estimation of uncertainties by the two experiments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantifier ist the **probability** to obtain the result. However, in order to calculate the probability we need to know the **distribution** of the measured data-points.

Suppose the data-points are normally distributed with mean value $\mu = 5$ and standard deviation $\sigma_x=3$. If we take $n=100$ data-points in a first experiment, the sample average is distributed as $\bar x \sim N(\mu, \sigma_x/\sqrt{n}) = N(5, 0.3)$. This is what you probably meant with your first statement.

Next, we perform a hypothesis test. The logic is as follows: Suppose the data-points come from $N(\mu, \sigma_x)$, what is the probability that we obtain a result which is *at least as extrem* as the result found in the second experiment? In order to be concrete, let's consider the one-sided hypothesis

> What is the probability to obtain $\bar x_2 \ge 6$, if we use $n_2=100$ data-points?
> Sidemark 1: For a posterior test we should consider the *two-sided* hypothesis test, because the result $x_2 = 4 \pm 0.3$ would raise the same question about bias. Sidemark 2: We should actually use the $t$ distribution. Rare events are much more likely for the $t$ distribution than for the normal distribution.

The calculation is straight forward: We utilise the normal distribution and obtain the result $P \approx 429ppm = 429 \cdot 10^{-6}$, where I used $ppm$ for "parts-per-million". This is called the **p-value** of the hypothesis test. For the $t$-distribution we obtain $p\approx 604ppm$.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightening answer. Could you also please elaborate on how to calculate the p-value? You have mentioned that the calculation is straight forward.

Comment: Also, is ppm same as parts per million? Does it mean that the probability is 0.0429% and 0.0604%?

Comment: I added the ppm definition. Thank's for pointing this out. In order to understand how to calc cumulated probabilities please read about hypothesis tests. Finally, you will have to use either a numeric table or a program to get the number.

Comment: Dear Semoi, your answer helped me in my work, and I have gratefully acknowledged your help in my paper: [Paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10509-021-04006-5), [Full Text](https://link.springer.com/epdf/10.1007/s10509-021-04006-5?sharing_token=KcBlr7cAF11g6aEoa2S83_e4RwlQNchNByi7wbcMAY5NWqJKRyY9HMYNiOh-pLQKcuROMipcdEHV_V-EHzsD8rqvbVYA_0ZWzYJcfqbZBq3aJF5H7inBGJ28VO_5GwIMJQX5S88REzof8zYy4c6f6044DC1dV3axhe8t5qM2XtA%3D)